# How do I hide the burger menu at certain sizes?

Tags: html, css, material-design

I tried to work with mdl. The website has to be in the responsive design. So i want to expand the burger menu into the header when the width is larger than 1024px.

I tried to make it invisible or hidden. But it either disabled the menu or as the screen got smaller i got the content of the menu on my site instead of the menu itself

```html
<style>
  @media only screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    .mdl-layout__drawer {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title"><i class="material-icons">
                portrait
                </i>  DerGeileGärtner</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    room
                    </i>   Sensor</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    settings
                    </i>   Einstellung</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    help
                    </i>   Hilfe</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    business
                    </i>   Impressum</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

It doesn't work at all if i use the mdl.layout__drawer class. It also doesn't work if i give the class an id, in these to cases it doesn't change anything. and it doesn't work if give the mdl-layout__drawer class another class, that's the case when it drops the content of the menu on the site instead.

[Picture of the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJwJ.png)
So the two on the left diappear when it gets too small which is good. the menu on the right either doesnt disappear the site gets too big or it disapperas when it gets to big but doesnt come back when it gets smaller. Instead i get the content from the menu on my site

Answer (score 0):

I saw that Material Design Lite already had an example for this component. You just need to set up the right structure for your menu.

You can take a look at the example here. 
[MDL Navigation Layout](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/layout)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header ">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title"><i class="material-icons">
                portrait
                </i>  DerGeileGärtner</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    room
                    </i>   Sensor</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    settings
                    </i>   Einstellung</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    help
                    </i>   Hilfe</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    business
                    </i>   Impressum</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title"><i class="material-icons">
                portrait
                </i>  DerGeileGärtner</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    room
                    </i>   Sensor</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    settings
                    </i>   Einstellung</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    help
                    </i>   Hilfe</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">
                    business
                    </i>   Impressum</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: i used the fixed one. And it got a class called large screens only. which makes the links on the left disappear if  the screen gets too small, which is good. I now want to have the menu on the right to disappear when the screen gets too big. That works but when the screen gets smaller the menu keeps being invisibile but the content gets thrown onto my page instead

Comment: There is a picture added now

Comment: Can you check my snippet above? I see no problem when scaling up and down the size of the viewport.